# Why do I get "% Warning: use /31 mask on non point-to-point interface cautiously" when I use a /31 subnet mask?

Tags: routing, ip, ipv4, subnet, interface

Why do I get `% Warning: use /31 mask on non point-to-point interface cautiously` when I use a `/31` subnet mask over Ethernet, and why am I not able to ping from R1 to R2 when both the interfaces have accepted the `/31` subnet mask and they both are directly connected, and in which conditions can I use `/31` without any trouble?

```
R1#show running-config interface fastEthernet 0/0
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 107 bytes
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 216.21.5.1 255.255.255.254
 shutdown
 duplex auto
 speed auto
end

R2#show running-config interface fastEthernet 0/0
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 107 bytes
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 216.21.5.2 255.255.255.254
 shutdown
 duplex auto
 speed auto
end
```

Topology:

[image]

Comment: I had the same question about the warning, although I did not expect them to ping as there is no broadcast address available which I believe would stop the whole process.

Comment: Actually, both addresses are broadcast addresses, and broadcast works because there is only one other device on the network. See _[RFC 3021, Using 31-Bit Prefixes on IPv4 Point-to-Point Links](https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3021.txt)_.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your problem is that you are addressing in two separate networks: `216.21.5.0/31` and `216.21.5.2/31`. The addresses you are using are in the same `/30` network, but two separate `/31` networks.

You need to set one address as `216.21.5.0` and the other address as `216.21.5.1`, or set one address as `216.21.5.2` and the other address as `216.21.5.3`.

The warning is because ethernet is a broadcast technology which can have multiple endpoints, but a `/31` network can only use two endpoints. If you were configuring it on a true point-to-point medium, I don't think you would get the warning.

Answer (score 4):

Using /31s is specified in [RFC 3021 (Using 31-Bit Prefixes on IPv4 Point-to-Point Links)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3021).

Not all operating systems support this, especially Windows. And there are probably other system out there which do not support this RFC.

So using a /31 will not work with every connection and router gives you a friendly warning.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you could do "no shutdown" on relevant interfaces :)

Answer (score -1):

Use a /30 prefix. A /31 prefix is not enough space for two hosts. You want R1 and R2 to be in the same network. A /30 network gives only two usable addresses which is enough for R1 and R2.

/30 = 255.255.255.252

Comment: Using a `/31` is perfectly acceptable for point-to-point links. It also gives you two addresses, and it doesn't waste two addresses like a `/30` does. This was approved in December 2000 (15 years ago!) by [RFC 3021, Using 31-Bit Prefixes on IPv4 Point-to-Point Links](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3021), and it is fully supported by Cisco.

Comment: I created a gns3 topology with 2 routers and assigned a /31 mask, I'm surprised that worked out fine. I was always told that a /30 mask could only accommodate 2 possible hosts, because of the network address and broadcast address.

Comment: It's true, `/30` can only accommodate two hosts, but it wastes two addresses for the network and broadcast addresses. That's why `/31` was introduced 15 years ago.