# Use of /30 instead of /31

Tags: ipv4, ip, subnet, security

Besides wasting IP addresses. Is there any other compelling reason to use a /31 subnet over a /30 on Point to Point links?

I am interested from a security perspective mainly.  Would a /31 be more secure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no particular security advantage.  RFC3021 cites addressing efficiency as the motivation for implementing /31's

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in [RFC 6164](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6164): "Using 127-Bit IPv6 Prefixes on Inter-Router Links". The abstract clearly mentions security as a motivation:

> On inter-router point-to-point links, it is useful, for security and other reasons, to use 127-bit IPv6 prefixes.

The security issues described are the "ping-pong issue" (routing loop) and neighbor cache exhaustion, but as mentioned in the document, for IPv4 the discussion is a bit more academic:

> The ping-pong issue happens in the case of IPv4 as well.  But due to
> the scarcity of IPv4 address space, the current practice is to assign
> long prefix lengths such as /30 or /31 [RFC3021](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3021)on point-to-point
> links; thus, the problem did not come to the fore.

Comment: This gives reasoning for a /127 for IPv6, but it does not give any additional security to use a /31 over a /30 in IPv4 as the OP asks. In IPv4 using either prevents the effects you describe, so it simply doesn’t provide another reason to use a /31 over a /30.

Comment: I don't disagree, but from the question I got the impression the OP was being curious rather then trying to solve a specific problem and felt this RFC was interesting reading material in this context. Sorry, I don't mind deleting the answer if it strays too much from the point.

Comment: While it doesn't seem to actually address the concern of the OP, I agree it does provide a relevant tangent to the OP's question (which is why I didn't down vote).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this previous question and it's answers will make thinks clearer:

[Why do I get "% Warning: use /31 mask on non point-to-point interface cautiously" when I use a /31 subnet mask?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/25991/why-do-i-get-warning-use-31-mask-on-non-point-to-point-interface-cautiously)

Comment: One of those days when you use google to find your own answers from a long time ago.  ;-)

Comment: It is particularly fun when you have one of those days when you Google to find an answer to your own question and come up with an answer you wrote a long time ago....